# Angular 2 http get querystring params

Tags: angularjs, ionic2, query-string, angular

Hopefully someone can help with this. I building an ionic 2 app which is based on the newer Angular 2, I am familiar with previous versions of Angular, but still trying to figure this whole typescript.

I have my API setup with basic get querystrings (e.g domain.com?state=ca&city=somename)

```
export class TestPage {
public state: string ='ca';
public city: string = null;
constructor(private http: Http){}

public submit() { 
   let url = "http://localhost/api"; 
   let payload = {"state": this.state, "city": this.city};
   this.$http.get(url, payload).subscribe(result => {
      //result
   }, err => {  
      //do something with the error 
   }
  )
 }
}
```

When I execute this it pulls my API url fine and I can get a response back, however none of the querystrings are being sent in the request. Its just sending `http://localhost/api`.  If I `console.log` the payload its fine.

Ultimately I am trying to get it to do `https://localhost/api?state=ca&city=example`

Looking at examples I can't really find anything straight-forward on this.

Is it not possible to take a payload on `http` with this newer version of Angular? The code above is just an example. I have many querystrings, which is why I was hoping to send a payload to it.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: ionic 2 is based on angular 2.. not angular 4..

Comment: Angular 4 is meant to be angular 2.4 I think. Googling it yield result that explain that. Angular.js is v1 and Angular 2 is v2 there isn't any v3 or v4 but some people, for some reason, call 2.3 and 2.4 Angular 3 and 4.

Comment: @GillesC no. The version is 4.0.0. Not 2.4.0. Angular now uses semantic versioning, and the 4.0 is an evolution of the 2.x version.

Comment: @GillesC [Angular 4.0.0 changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400-invisible-makeover-2017-03-23) and [angular 2.4.8 changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#248-2017-02-18)

Comment: @limit: read the API documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Http-class.html. It should be `this.http.get(url, { params: payload })`

Comment: @JBNizet - Thanks.. this seems to work with $post, but not $get. I get a payload when using post.

Comment: @limit please edit your question from angular 4 to angular 2. as it will help others to resolve there issue.

Comment: @Shivam Updated it. But the angular docs list it as version 4.0 - https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/

Comment: @limit  Angular 4 is the latest release of angular framework. But Ionic 2 is built on top of Angular 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Http.get method takes an object that implements *RequestOptionsArgs* as a second parameter.

The search field of that object can be used to set a string or a URLSearchParams object.

An example:

```
// Parameters obj-
 let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
 params.set('state', this.state);
 params.set('city', this.city);

 //Http request-
 return this.http.get('http://localhost/api', {
   search: params
 }).subscribe(
   (response) => this.onGetForecastResult(response.json()), 
   (error) => this.onGetForecastError(error.json()), 
   () => this.onGetForecastComplete()
 );
```

Documentation: [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Http-class.html)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This worked.  I wonder if it get be looped off a single payload, so I don't have to set every param.

Comment: You can apply extra logic for that. Cheers!